# what does pkill -KILL -f java do?

Tags: linux, bash, operating-system

I am trying to understand what exactly each line of this code does:

```
cat << EOF > /tmp/kill_loop.sh
#!/bin/bash
while true;
do
    pkill -KILL java
    pkill -KILL python
    sleep 1
done
EOF

nohup /bin/bash /tmp/kill_loop.sh &
```

but most importantly what pkill -KILL -f does

Comment: Try `man pkill`

Comment: Just run `man pkill` and you will find answer.

Comment: [pkill man page](https://www.google.com/search?q=pkill+man+page) may be useful to you. Also see [Difference between help, info and man command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/19451/56041) on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: tried man kill but i still dont get what -KILL does ? or how it selects which java process to kill as it doesn't go by PID

Comment: See: http://explainshell.com/

Answer (score -1):

From the man page for `pkill`:

> The pkill command searches    the process table on the running system and
>        signals all processes that match the criteria given on the command line.

The `-KILL` argument is specifying which Linux process signal to send:

```sh
Signal name Signal value    Effect
SIGHUP      1               Hangup
SIGINT      2               Interrupt from keyboard
SIGQUIT     3               Quit
SIGABRT     6               Abort
SIGKILL     9               Kill signal
SIGTERM     15              Termination signal - allow an orderly shutdown
SIGSTOP     17,19,23        Stop the process
```

See https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill and https://linux.die.net/man/7/signal for more info.

Edit:  In your example, java is being passed in as the pattern operand:

> pattern - 
>   Specifies an Extended Regular Expression for matching against the process names or command lines.

Comment: thanks for the answer, and specifying java/python, how does that help in finding which process to kill?

Comment: You would typically use the `ps` command to figure out which process to kill if you weren't trying to kill a process whose name you already knew (like java).

Comment: so in the above command, java is supposed to be the name of the process? and not the file extension or language ?

Comment: That's correct. Java source code typically lives in a file with a `.java` extension. One invokes a process called `javac` to compile the `.java` file into a `.class` file. Then, to actually run that compiled java code, one invokes the `java` process. So killing the process named `java` kills any running java code on the machine.